# How to get the default, max, min value of Video Proc Amp/Camera Control parameters from UVC camera?

Tags: c++, windows, uvc

I want to get the default, max, and min values of control parameters from UVC camera like the picture.
[image]

I try to get the default value with the below function. However, it only gets the current value of XU control and I cannot get the default values of XU control or any value of **Video Proc Amp**/**Camera Control** like the above picture.

```
//Function to set/get parameters of UVC extension unit
HRESULT SetGetExtensionUnit(GUID xuGuid, DWORD dwExtensionNode, ULONG xuPropertyId, ULONG flags, void* data, int len, ULONG* readCount)
{
    GUID pNodeType;
    IUnknown* unKnown;
    IKsControl* ks_control = NULL;
    IKsTopologyInfo* pKsTopologyInfo = NULL;
    KSP_NODE kspNode;

    HRESULT hr = pVideoSource->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IKsTopologyInfo), (void**)&pKsTopologyInfo);
    CHECK_HR_RESULT(hr, "IMFMediaSource::QueryInterface(IKsTopologyInfo)");

    hr = pKsTopologyInfo->get_NodeType(dwExtensionNode, &pNodeType);
    CHECK_HR_RESULT(hr, "IKsTopologyInfo->get_NodeType(...)");

    hr = pKsTopologyInfo->CreateNodeInstance(dwExtensionNode, IID_IUnknown, (LPVOID*)&unKnown);
    CHECK_HR_RESULT(hr, "ks_topology_info->CreateNodeInstance(...)");

    hr = unKnown->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IKsControl), (void**)&ks_control);
    CHECK_HR_RESULT(hr, "ks_topology_info->QueryInterface(...)");

    kspNode.Property.Set = xuGuid;              // XU GUID
    kspNode.NodeId = (ULONG)dwExtensionNode;   // XU Node ID
    kspNode.Property.Id = xuPropertyId;         // XU control ID
    kspNode.Property.Flags = flags;             // Set/Get request

    hr = ks_control->KsProperty((PKSPROPERTY)&kspNode, sizeof(kspNode), (PVOID)data, len, readCount);
    CHECK_HR_RESULT(hr, "ks_control->KsProperty(...)");

done:
    SafeRelease(&ks_control);
    return hr;
}


int main(void) {
...

      SetGetExtensionUnit(xuGuidUVC, 2, 1, 
                          KSPROPERTY_TYPE_GET | KSPROPERTY_TYPE_TOPOLOGY, 
                          (void*)data, 1, &readCount)  // XU_FUNC1 Get Value Pass

      SetGetExtensionUnit(xuGuidUVC, 2, 1, 
                          KSPROPERTY_TYPE_DEFAULTVALUES | KSPROPERTY_TYPE_TOPOLOGY, 
                          (void*)data, 1, &readCount);   // XU_FUNC1 Get Value FAIL

      SetGetExtensionUnit(xuGuidUVC, 1, 2, 
                          KSPROPERTY_TYPE_GET | KSPROPERTY_TYPE_TOPOLOGY, 
                          (void*)data, 2, &readCount);   // BRIGHTNESS Get Value FAIL

...
}
```

How could I get the default value but the current value from XU control?

I think I cannot get the parameters of **Video Proc Amp**/**Camera Control** because I set the XU GUID but the correct GUID.

How could I get the correct GUID and get the default, max, min values from UVC cameras?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my question. I use `IAMVideoProcAmp` and `IAMVideoProcAmp` to realize this function.

```
HRESULT hr;
IAMVideoProcAmp* procAmp = NULL;
IAMCameraControl* control = NULL;

...

hr = pVideoSource->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&procAmp));
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = procAmp->GetRange(prop, &min, &max, &step, &def, &caps);
    procAmp->Release();
    return hr;
}

...

hr = pVideoSource->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&control));
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = control->GetRange(prop, &min, &max, &step, &def, &caps);
    control->Release();
    return hr;
}
```